# what's wrong about my methodology?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Academia Stack Exchange post: [is my spreadsheet considered a framework?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/118384/is-my-spreadsheet-considered-a-framework)

I posted a question about my methodology for generating a theoretical framework but some lads responded by asking some irrelevant questions(in my opinion) that could not help me solve my problem. I need some Academics' opinions on the matter    . best regards

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the issue is that it is not clear to me what you are asking about. There appears to be a lot of jargon (framework, domain, class diagram) whose meaning is not clear to others. I think this mm is making it difficult for people to figure out what you are asking.

The SE system is different than other online communities. Please take a look at our [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help). What the comments were trying to do is guide you to provide information that people think might help clarify your question. They may not be the right questions to ask, but there is something unclear about your question.

Instead of being highly abstract in the question, you might want to try and provide more specifics. Instead of assuming the terminology is known, provide links or references to the key concepts, or better yet descriptions/definitions.

Comment: I think I have a different background than others. thank you

Comment: @WonderBoy you potentially do, but if you do not provide us with any information, we cannot tailor the answer to fit your background.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is off-topic because it is about the *content of your research* which is explicitly off-topic for Academia.SE (see https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Since you are new to StackExchange, note that every stack has a definition for what is on- and off-topic, and it is decided by those communities. If you want a community to change what they define as on-topic the correct way to address that is to start a meta conversation about it.

In addition, calling out people who are trying to help (including politely letting you know your question is off-topic) and accusing them of being here for reputation alone are both ways to come off as rude, and "be nice" is a core principle behind the StackExchange framework.

Comment: I guess it's one of the policies that stackexchange needs to change. you can't throw the word "off topic" when you just didn't understand the meaning of the question or it's not your specialty. theoretical framework are made for a variety of subjects that touches all the backgrounds. I just want to know from people who had made such frameworks how they managed to do so, what's their methodology?

Comment: @WonderBoy I encourage you to spend a bit more time on stack exchange before opining on the policies here; like you, I have been skeptical of some of the policies at SE but for the most part over time have learned why they are as they are. I'm sorry, but even with clarification, your question is still about the content of your research and therefore off-topic. You are asking a question that is specific to your research and person you should be asking for advice on your theoretical framework is your academic advisor.

Comment: understood. thank you!